# MSSQL display percentage calculated from two columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in MSSQL called 'Bjob_History' that contains results from some backup jobs, the table looks like this

```
 ObjectName  SuccessCount  Failcount
 job1        80            2
 job2        80            1
```

I'd like to run a query against each job individually that returns the success rate as a percentage, I would like the percentage returned to one decimal place so if I ran the query against Job1 it would return only "97.6%"

I literally want the result to just return the percentage, not the objectname and the percentage, so the result from the query should look like

"97.6%"

I don't have any idea where to start here, any help at all would be much appreciated!

thanks in advance

Comment: You know....object naming is really pretty important. When you abbreviate a name and create a whole new connotation it might be worth going back and naming your table something a little less....potentially misunderstood.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well I suppose your SuccessCount and FailCount are ints. So this one should be your go:

```
SELECT 
ObjectName,
CONVERT(VARCHAR,(convert(decimal(12,2),SuccessRate) / (convert(decimal(12,2),SuccessRate)  + convert(decimal(12,2),FailRate))) * 100) + '%'
FROM Temp
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8194d/7

If you don't want ObjectName to be displayed, but you want to display success rate for Job1 go for:

```
SELECT 
CONVERT(VARCHAR,(convert(decimal(12,2),SuccessRate) / (convert(decimal(12,2),SuccessRate)  + convert(decimal(12,2),FailRate))) * 100) + '%'
FROM Temp
WHERE ObjectName = 'Job1'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. This query returns the Objectname and the percentage, the percentages are also all at 0%. ?

Comment: I think the multiply needed to come earlier in the query, I have tweeked it to this     SELECT 
     ObjectName , 
     CONVERT(VARCHAR,(SuccessCount *100) / (SuccessCount  + Failcount)) + '%' AS SuccessRate
FROM 
     Bjob_History