# Display percentage from two sql columns

Tags: php, sql, division, percentage

This is a small section of code i've been working with.

```
<?php
$rank = 0;
$rank = 0;
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT m.memberID, username,email,target,type, ifnull(t.total,0) as total, ifnull(m.total,0) as totalp FROM `members` as m 
left join (
select s.memberID, sum(amount) total  from sponsors as s group by s.memberID
) t on t.memberid = m.memberid
left join (
select s.memberID, sum(amount) total  from sponsors as s group by s.memberID
) p on p.memberid = m.memberid Where type= 'business'
ORDER BY t.total DESC, p.total DESC, username ASC");

while($row = mysql_fetch_object($sql)) 
{
    echo "<tr>";
        $rank = $rank + 1;
        echo "<td><center>$rank</center></td>";
        echo "<td>$row->username</td>";
        echo "<td>$row->total</td>";
        echo "<td>$row->target</td>";
        echo "<td>$row->here i want percentage</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

What I would like to do is display the percentage of total/target in the final column of my table. Not sure what the best way to do this is and would be keen to hear some ideas for this.

I did try doing it just as total/target in the echo but thinking it probably needs to be evaluated earlier as a variable or something? Whatever i tried didn't work anyway...

Looked at this but not sure how to implement it in my scenario - [MSSQL display percentage calculated from two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28158372/mssql-display-percentage-calculated-from-two-columns)

Comment: there are two ways to do that. 1.you can do with single query, 2.get data from db and calculate with percentage and display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
 <?php
    $rank = 0;
    $rank = 0;
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT m.memberID, username,email,target,type, ifnull(t.total,0) as total, ifnull(m.total,0) as totalp, (ifnull(t.total,0)/target)*100 as present FROM `members` as m 
    left join (
    select s.memberID, sum(amount) total  from sponsors as s group by s.memberID
    ) t on t.memberid = m.memberid
    left join (
    select s.memberID, sum(amount) total  from sponsors as s group by s.memberID
    ) p on p.memberid = m.memberid Where type= 'business'
    ORDER BY t.total DESC, p.total DESC, username ASC");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($sql)) 
    {
        echo "<tr>";
            $rank = $rank + 1;
            echo "<td><center>$rank</center></td>";
            echo "<td>$row->username</td>";
            echo "<td>$row->total</td>";
            echo "<td>$row->target</td>";
            echo "<td>$row->present</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: thats awesome!! thanks heaps - what should i do to make this rounded so the percentage is 0 dp?

Answer (score 0):

Here is logic 
((cast("A/B" as float)/"C") * 100.00) AS "D%"
all value must be integer and when you are dividing them it must be convert as a float so calculation goes correctly. 
Hope it will work for you.